# PowerShell script to select and remember an Azure VM name and resource group

Tags: powershell, azure

By using the cmdlet `Get-AzureRmVM` I show a list of VMs in an Azure subscription. Then by using a keyboard user input like (1,2,3..) I want to store into variables the name and the resource group name of the selected VM

```
Get-AzureRmVM


ResourceGroupName         Name   Location          VmSize  OsType             NIC Provision
                                                                                   ingState
-----------------         ----   --------          ------  ------             --- ---------

NW-TRAINING                VM1 westeurope Standard_D2s_v3 Windows          vm1518 Succeeded
NW-TRAINING                VM2 westeurope Standard_D2s_v3 Windows          vm2357 Succeeded
TESTDNS               machine1 westeurope Standard_DS1_v2   Linux     machine1813 Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to assign the result of the `Get-AzureRmVm` to a variable and then you can access the specific VM using the index. e. g.:

```
$vms = Get-AzureRmVm

$index = Read-Host "Please enter the VM index"
$vms[$index] | Select-Object Name, ResourceGroupName
```